# Codeigniter personal message error

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, error-handling

Helo. After sending message getting error: 
is currently unable to handle this request.
    HTTP ERROR 500 
it's ekkator school managment system.

How can i fix it ?

```
<div class="mail-header" style="padding-bottom: 27px ;">
<!-- title -->
<h3 class="mail-title">
    <?php echo get_phrase('write_new_message'); ?>
</h3>
```

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url() . 'index.php?admin/message/send_new/', array('class' => 'form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>


<div class="form-group">
    <label for="subject"><?php echo get_phrase('recipient'); ?>:</label>
    <br><br>
    <select class="form-control select2" name="reciever" required>

        <option value=""><?php echo get_phrase('select_a_user'); ?></option>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo get_phrase('student'); ?>">
            <?php
            $students = $this->db->get('student')->result_array();
            foreach ($students as $row):
                ?>

                <option value="student-<?php echo $row['student_id']; ?>">
                    - <?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo get_phrase('teacher'); ?>">
            <?php
            $teachers = $this->db->get('teacher')->result_array();
            foreach ($teachers as $row):
                ?>

                <option value="teacher-<?php echo $row['teacher_id']; ?>">
                    - <?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="<?php echo get_phrase('parent'); ?>">
            <?php
            $parents = $this->db->get('parent')->result_array();
            foreach ($parents as $row):
                ?>

                <option value="parent-<?php echo $row['parent_id']; ?>">
                    - <?php echo $row['name']; ?></option>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </optgroup>
    </select>
</div>


<div class="compose-message-editor">
    <textarea row="2" class="form-control wysihtml5" data-stylesheet-url="assets/css/wysihtml5-color.css"
        name="message" placeholder="<?php echo get_phrase('write_your_message'); ?>"
        id="sample_wysiwyg" required></textarea>
</div>
<br>
<!-- File adding module -->
<div class="">
  <input type="file" class="form-control file2 inline btn btn-info" name="attached_file_on_messaging" accept=".pdf, .doc, .jpg, .jpeg, .png" data-label="<i class='entypo-upload'></i> Browse" />
</div>
```

---

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-icon pull-right">
    <?php echo get_phrase('send'); ?>
    <i class="entypo-mail"></i>
</button>
```

Error from comment.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Email_model::notify_email() in /home/mtschool/public_html/sms/application/models/Crud_model.php on line 343 A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Warning Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mtschool/public_html/sms/application/models/Crud_model.php:343) Filename: core/Common.php Line Number: 569 Backtrace: A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error Message: Call to undefined method Email_model::notify_email() Filename: models/Crud_model.php Line Number: 343 Backtrace:

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Maybe because you have a  question mark in form url `?` can you show the echo of the form action.

Comment: Plus if you use form_open you don't need base_url

Comment: Follow these instructions: https://imgur.com/a/aVuaU to turn on error reporting so we see something other than a 500 and the actual error

Comment: You error now that you&#39;ve updated your question is self explanatory the method notify email cannot be found either because you didn&#39;t load the model or it doesn&#39;t exist. It would be useful to post the controller code where this is called e.g. send_new